# Why can't I get tokens inserted in to HMTL or Text fields of System Template Messages

Tags: tokens

Clicking on the Token under Tokens has zero effect

Answer (score 1):

This was a regression introduced in 4.7. It gets fixed by applying https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10149 change.

JIRA filed here - https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20418